# Designing a Matlab filter from a Laplace equation

Tags: filtering, matlab, simulink

I have a Laplace Transfer function that I wish to use in a high pass filter. I am trying to design a filter inside Matlab that will use this function using FDAtool but I don't understand how the parameters and coefficients this tool uses relates to the Laplace function I have.

Can anyone provide some information or links regarding the relationship between a function and the filter that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use a [Transfer Fcn](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/transferfcn.html) block (or a [Discrete Transfer Fcn](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/discretetransferfcn.html) block if it's discrete) since you already have the Laplace transfer function? FDAtool is for designing a filter as far as I know. It sounds like your filter is already designed.

Comment: Didn't even see that one! How do you determine the coefficients for numerator and denominator?

Comment: From your original question, it sounds as if you already have them since you have the Laplace transfer function. They're just the coefficients of the transfer function.